# Randomly sort all non-ordered rows

Tags: postgresql, testing

Is there a way to get PostgreSQL to randomly order query results that haven't been ordered by an `ORDER BY`? I think this would be a useful way to seek out bugs caused by an implicit reliance on the order of DB results.

Comment: Interesting idea but is it a bug to expect `select * from generate_series(1,5)` to come out ordered? And that's just the first example that comes to mind.

Comment: In the real world people use databases in CRUDdy ways, have test suites for their applications that could benefit from this testing and don't do a whole lot of `select * from generate_series()`.

Comment: Tests suites typically need the results in a specific order to verify them. So the test suite would need to know which queries might be artificially reordered and which queries might not. At that point you might just as well let it add `ORDER BY random()` to the first kind of queries and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there is no ORDER BY clause, the results is a non-ordered set, so the order that the rows are returned should be considered 'random' anyway.
However, PostgreSQL will typically fetch the rows in the most efficient manner, which may be the order they were inserted.
You can 'work around' this by performing a mock update, which will move the updated rows to the 'end' of the line. You can repeat several dissimilar updates using modulo, random or any other form that will filter a 'seemingly random' subset.
Something along the lines of:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Foo;

CREATE TABLE Foo (Col1 INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO Foo (Col1)
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 20);

SELECT * FROM Foo;

UPDATE  Foo
SET     Col1 = Col1
WHERE   Col1%3 = 0;

UPDATE  Foo
SET     Col1 = Col1
WHERE   Col1%5 = 0;

SELECT * FROM Foo;
```

Do this in development environment only, not in production of course :-)

HTH

Comment: "the order they were inserted." or later updated (because in MVCC an update is basically just a delete + insert)

Comment: Well, what about the case of `SELECT foo, bar, baz ORDER BY foo, bar`.  Code could still have an implicit dependency on the order of baz within that output, and it would be neat if you could randomize the order of baz within (foo, bar) to shake out any implicit dependencies on baz.